# How much information would a network protector need to determine if a backfeed is due to feeder failure or power export?

Tags: mains, power-engineering, distribution-network

Many downtown or otherwise densely built-up areas, as well as some major metropoles (much of NYC, most notably), use *secondary network* electrical service to maximize service reliability and keep utility equipment costs reasonable.  This works well, until you start adding a high degree of distributed generation capacity (whether renewable or not) to the network.  Then, under low loads, the *network protectors* start tripping out, as they're designed to identify any power export from the secondary network as a sign of a faulted or shut-off primary cable and trip.  The resulting "pumping" (short cycling) of the network protectors can damage them beyond repair, meaning that DG additions on secondary network services are often prohibited or severely restricted.

However, the downstream/upstream logic in network protectors only looks at *local* power flow at that network protector, with no awareness of what other protectors in the network are seeing.  In theory, though, assuming the network transformers all share the load/generation equally, a faulted or shut-off primary cable can easily be distinguished from a true power export situation by looking at the direction of power flow on a network-wide basis.  Specifically, under that equal-sharing assumption, an export situation would be identified by *all* the network protectors registering an export of power, while a faulted or shut-off primary cable would stand out like a sore thumb as the *only* cable trying to export power, while the remaining network protectors still register power *imports*.

That raises two questions, though.  First, how far from the equal-sharing ideal do actual secondary distribution networks operate at?  And second, in a network running at practical levels of transformer-to-transformer imbalance, how much knowledge of the rest of the network's power flows is needed for a network protector to distinguish between *bona fide* power export and backfeed due to a failed primary line?  I ask this because I wonder if some means of inter-network-protector communications/restraint could be used to allow network services to support deep DG penetration without the need for a costly DG "overlay" service system.

Comment: Interesting question. I'm guessing people are, or about to start, reprogramming/reconfiguring existing systems with this in mind. In the UK you're allowed to add a limited amount of generation to a single phase (using G83/2 approved components) with only a notification to the utility. The sum of notifications on any segment presumably determines how much reverse flow may be expected from that segment. Export in excess of that is clearly a fault.